# Complex Matchstick puzzle

Tags: mathematics, matches

This is my toughest invention so far, not sure if it's already been done but here it goes.

Move a single stick to obtain a correct equality. (To be clear: the stick needs to be moved and placed down to be part of the new figure; not 'removed').

[image]

Comment: Must all numbers be represented as proper Roman or Arabic numerals?

Comment: I'd never seen this before, very clever

Comment: I want to answer, but does a rot13(vardhnyvgl) count?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is this:

> [image]

where

> $e^{-i\pi}=3-4=-1$

The title alludes to

> the complex number $i$ found in the solution.

Comment: Inconsistent that a match is `i` in one case and `1` in another

Comment: not to be that guy, but technically, no match represents the number 1. the roman numerals are iii and iv. I will grant you that they're still interpreted differently haha

Comment: @juicifer to be fair they're all interpreted as `i`

Comment: true, but they certainly don't mean the same thing

Comment: @somebody Or rather all interpreted as `I` (capitalized `i`).

Answer (score 1):

My answer:

> $-8^{-iii} = ii-iv$

Comment: I was really hoping that would be right too but -8^(1/3) = -2, not -8^-3.

Comment: I always intended to start with a bang. How embarrassing for me to have for gotten.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have bad stick "handwriting"

> [image: 8-3=3+2]

This gives you

> 8-3 = 3 + 2

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to interpret the "-III" as "minus three" instead of "to the negative three" due to its placement in an exponent position

Comment: It's a bit of a stretch, but that was what I was referring to with the bad handwriting comment